# Duplicate function definition in C code - What can be the reason?

Tags: c, function, microcontroller

While analyzing a microcontroller project I stumbled across some code smells I can't explain to myself.

There are 2 functions that are completely identical. These 2 functions are called multiple times from a state machine. I'm wondering why someone copied and renamed a function just to call it from different code locations?

Functions are called timerfunction_display_handler and temp_timerfunction_display_handler as you can see below.

```
 static void timerfunction_display_handler(uint8_t i)
 {
     if(tommy_context[i].step == WARMING_STEP)
     {
       if(general_context.config_value[TEMP_STEP_SWITCH] == 2)
       {
         cleaning_handler_temp_no_blink(i);    
       }

       else
       {
         cleaning_handler_step_no_blink(i);
       }
     }

     /*normal cooking*/
     else if(tommy_context[i].step <= MAX_COOKING_STEP)
         {
       set_tommy_led(NOTHING,secure_context[i].cooking_step,NOTHING,1u,i,(i+1u)%2u,i);
         }

     else
     {
       set_tommy_led(NOTHING,P,NOTHING,1u,i,(i+1u)%2u,i);
     }
 }

static void temp_timerfunction_display_handler(uint8_t i)
{
// same code as code
}
```

Any hint or suggestion is very appreciated.

**************** Update **************

Yes, these two functions are in the same c file, and there 2(4) more functions that follow the same (anti)-pattern.

**************** Update **************

Best Regards

Hannes

Comment: The code may have been generated by a code generator which isn't clever enough to avoid duplicate functions.

Comment: Well, i guess people sometimes just write bad code... I can't think of any legitimate reason to have 2 functions that are 100% identical

Comment: Since the second on is called `temp`, which usually stands for temporary, my guess would be that it has been implemented at some point for debugging (and at this time the content was probably different), and at some point is has been forgotten and just stayed there. You should probably ask the provider of the code

Comment: Maybe it's just code smell. I don't see any reason for this unless the preprocessor symbols are different for the two functions, but that would be code smell as well.

Comment: Are they in the same C file?

Comment: What @Chelmy88 says is likely: "Hey, I need 'thingx' from your stuff to test mine"..."Well, I've written thingx but not fully tested it yet - if you are desperate, just copy it for now"...

Comment: Maybe it was just a copy&paste mistake to rearrange the source code in a more readable manner, following that what @Jabberwocky said. - Is this the exact code which is in question? Is the second function definition immediately behind the other in the same C file?

Comment: @MartinJames I don't get what is you point

Comment: @Chelmy88 ..that you are probably right.  IME, your explanation for the copy is the most likely:)

Comment: did you ask the author, what did they say about it?

Comment: I think that the functional programming tag makes no sense here